# Private alternative to Google Docs?

Tags: software-recommendation, google-drive

Is there software to install on an ubuntu server, and then use to collaboratively edit text files, sometimes adding some attachments? it's important that no data is lost if 2 people save the same doc with different contents at the same time. I've found seafile, but it seems too complicated considering it need 3 ports to work, and requires manual installation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [Etherpad](http://etherpad.org/), a nice alternative to Google Docs based on Node.js. We used it in some projects with relative success.

Answer (score 6):

You can also try [Firepad](http://www.firepad.io/#1) which is based on Firebase, and is server independent. Only using Javascript.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[ownCloud](http://owncloud.org/) is an open source, private cloud server, like dropbox or google drive, but you can install it locally. They recently added a collaborative document editing feature that you can see in action at the top of this page: http://owncloud.org/six/

I have only briefly tested the document editing aspect, but the file archival aspect has worked great across multiple machines and platforms. Just like with dropbox, you always retain a local copy of your files.

Answer (score 0):

We at collatebox are creating a shared 'spreadsheet-like' offering for the private cloud / on premise installations. This will allow you cell level control with a mobile template off-the-shelf. Write to info (at) collatebox.com to get onto early release list

Answer (score -1):

You could try http://www.collatebox.com/ , or simply write to them to kow if they have a solution for that.